# Euler's Characteristic Formula and cicruits of length $n$

Tags: graph-theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph
It is proven that if a planar graph has no circuits of length $3$, then
$$e\leq 2v-4$$

(circuit is a closed path)

Can we also show that if there is no circuit of length $k$, then there is a smaller upper bound on $e$?
Sorry if this is silly question.

For example, the proof is that if there are no circuits of length $3$, then
the degree of each region is at minimum $4$.
And $$\sum_{R \text{is a region}}\mathrm{deg}(R) = \sum_{v\in V}\mathrm{deg}(v)$$
$$\sum_{R \text{is a region}}\mathrm{deg}(R) \geq 4r$$
where $r$ is number of regions.
By Handshaking Lemma,
$$2e \geq 4r \\ e \geq 2r$$
and by Euler's Characteristic equation,
$$r = 2-v+e \\ \implies e \geq 2v-4.$$

---

I feel like this upper bound can be smaller, if we assume that there are no circuits of length $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.
If there are no circuits of length $k$, then
$$\mathrm{deg}(R) \geq k+1$$
So,
$$\sum_{R \ \text{is a region}} \mathrm{deg}(R) = 2e \\ \geq (k+1)r$$
Using Euler's Characteristic equation,
$$r = 2-v+e \\ (k+1)r = 2(k+1) - (k+1)v + (k+1)e \\ 2e \geq 2(k+1) - (k+1)v + (k+1)e \\ e \leq \frac{1}{k-1} \left((k+1)v -2(k+1)\right)$$

I'm not able to see any mention of this online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that in your proof you assume that the graph contains no cycles of length *less than* $k$, that is the *girth* of the graph (that is, the length of the shortest cycle contained in it) is well defined (that is the graph contains at least one cycle) and is at least $k+1$. Then this bound is known. See, for instance Theorem 2.4 [here](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~svs/475/planar.pdf) or Exercise 6.1.30 [here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~kindred/cuc-only/math104/hmwk-solns/hm8sol.pdf) or Theorem (Jungnickel's 1.5.3) [here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mrm/Teaching/DiscreteMaths/Slides/PlanarGraphs.pdf) or Theorem 6.12 [here](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/teaching/ws05/graph-theory/graph-theory-5.pdf).